# In the morning prayers of Birkhot Hatorah, what does וְהַשְׁכָּמַת בֵּית הַמִּדְרָשׁ שַׁחֲרִית וְעַרְבִית practically mean?

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, shacharis-morning-prayer

This appears in Birkhot Hatorah, as:

> אֵֽלּוּ דְבָרִים שֶׁאָדָם אוֹכֵל פֵּרוֹתֵיהֶם בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה וְהַקֶּֽרֶן קַיֶּֽמֶת לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא... וְהַשְׁכָּמַת בֵּית הַמִּדְרָשׁ שַׁחֲרִית וְעַרְבִית
>
> These are precepts, the fruits of which man enjoys in this world, [while] the principal [reward] is preserved for him in the World-to-Come. ...early attendance in the House of Study morning and evening..

I believe these are derived from [Shabbos 127a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.127a.13).

But practically speaking- what does it mean? If I go to a בית כנסת‎ or בית תפילה‎ for שַחֲרִית‎, and it starts at 8am and I get there at 7:59, do I fulfill the מצוה?

Also ,in this context, is בֵּית הַמִּדְרָשׁ the same as בית כנסת or בית תפילה‎? i.e. Is it about tefilla or learning?

How does one properly fulfill this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.127b.1?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) takes it as learning.

See also Yaavetz quoted by R' Eliashiv who is bothered by the phrase simply meaning learning, as then it is identical to תלמוד תורה and therefore takes it as simply learning adjacent- preparing for those who are learning.

> **הערות הגרי"ש אלישיב ליקוטים פאה פרק ראשון (א)**
> מה נכלל בת"ת דמתניתין
> ותלמוד תורה כנגד כולן. בר"ש הביא מ"ש במסכת שבת קכ"ז ע"א משנה זו עם עוד הוספות והשכמת בית המדרש שחרית וערבית והמגדל בניו לתלמוד תורה ואמרינן בגמרא שם ע"ב דלא תנן אלו במתניתין משום שכלול בתלמוד תורה. ונראה דהמגדל בניו לתלמוד תורה היינו בכה"ג דאמרינן בקידושין כ"ט ע"ב דמי שיש לו די רק לאחד ללמוד תורה מי עדיף הוא או בנו ואמרינן בגמ' דהוא קודם לבנו אמנם אמרינן התם שאם בנו חריף יותר בנו עדיף. ונראה דהיינו דקאמר הכא המגדל בניו לת"ת דמיירי שהוא אינו כ"כ מסוגל ללמוד ובנו מסוגל ומגדל בניו לת"ת דבהא הרי זה נחשב כאילו הוא עצמו לומד ולכן כלול הוא בתלמוד תורה. **ובהגהות יעבץ** בשבת שם מקשה על השכמת בית המדרש שחרית וערבית דהיינו ממש תלמוד תורה ואינו שני דברים ומתרץ דמיירי באחד שאינו מסוגל ללמוד תורה **והוא משכים ובא לביהמ"ד קודם שיבואו הלומדים ומסדר הספסלים ומכין המקום ללימוד ומכין להם לשתות דבזה נחשב כאילו הוא עצמו לומד.** (וע"ע בהערות קידושין מ' ע"א).